# Python adding values from one list to those of another

Tags: python, list

I have a series of lists in format:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

How can i add together the corresponding values to make a new list, for example:

Add 1 and 1 together, 2 and 2 together...

```
c = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
```

Note: There are the same amount of values in each list.

Comment: [*zip*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `zip` with `list comprehension`: -

```
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

`zip` creates a `list` of n-elements tuple, when used with `n` lists. So, here you would get a list of `2-element` tuple:

```
>>> zip(a, b)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]
```